# Find prefix cms in mysql DB

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system

I want get prefix from DB of CMS.
I make this code, but it not work when if in db is more CMS(Joomla, Opencart, Wordpress) or make backup. Can I access to prefix more gracefully?

```
        $this->connectDB();
        $result = mysql_query("show tables;");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
          $allRows[] = $row[0];
        }
        $index = preg_grep("/^.+_user$/", $allRows);
        $pieces = explode("_", array_pop($index));
        $this->_prefix=$pieces[0]."_"
```

;

Answer (score 0):

Try as follow

```
$this->connectDB();
        $result = mysql_query("show tables;");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
          $allRows[] = $row;
        }
        $index = preg_grep("/^.+_user$/", $allRows);
        $pieces = explode("_", array_pop($index));
        $this->_prefix=$pieces[0]."_"
```